# Derby db data included in project?

Tags: java, derby

I'm currently working on a project for school with a rather big data model. Right now I use the constructor of the model class to fill it with static data. Now I want to get rid of that and put all the data in a database. But without the need of a external server. I have to hand over the project in the end to have it rated and getting a 0% rating because my internet blacks out yet again would be very disappointing.

After quick look around I found out about [derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/). But I'm unsure where the thing stores its data. Is the database + data included in the project? Even when I export it as a .jar? If not is there any alternative that does these two things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the explanations you're looking for are most easily found here:

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/devguide/cdevdvlp21955.html

and

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/devguide/cdevdvlp40724.html

Specifically, the second link takes you to the section of the documentation describing how a database is stored on your file system, and how you can package a (read-only) database into a jar file if you want.

Comment: That was indeed what I was looking for! And this also means that derby is the tool I was looking for. Thank for the conformation!